# How to select full left table and where condition match records from right table?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, outer-join, right-join

Please some one tell me how to do this stuff. i have two tables , i need to select entire first table(pages) and from sencond table where user_id = 1

**table 1: page**

```
--------------------------------------
  page_id  |  page_url |   details   |  
--------------------------------------
      1    |    xxxx   |   wdredrr   |
      2    |    yyyy   |   rdsacsa   |
      3    |    zzzz   |   rscsacc   |
      4    |    aaaa   |   xdsxsxs   |
      5    |    bbbb   |   drxcraa   |
--------------------------------------
```

**table 2: control**

```
-------------------------------------
control_id |  page_id  |   user_id  |  
-------------------------------------
      1    |      1     |      1    |
      2    |      3     |      1    |
      3    |      4     |      1    |
      4    |      1     |      2    |
      5    |      2     |      2    |
-------------------------------------
```

and this is what expecting output.

**expecting output**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
  page_id  |  page_url |   details  | control_id |   user_id  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
      1    |    xxxx   |   wdredrr   |      1     |      1    |
      2    |    yyyy   |   rdsacsa   |    null    |    null   |
      3    |    zzzz   |   rscsacc   |      2     |      1    |
      4    |    aaaa   |   xdsxsxs   |    null    |    null   |
      5    |    bbbb   |   drxcraa   |      3     |      1    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

**pages JOIN control ON page.page_id = control.page_id WHERE control.user_id = '1'**

please someone help to solve this problem. i tried with LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN but i get user_id = 1 matched rows only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inner join` will check if the related data is available with the join condition in the related tables and hence it will filter out unmatched data. You need to use `left join` and the conditions in the `joining clause` something as

```
select 
p.*,
c.control_id,
c.user_id 
from page p left join control c on c.page_id = p.page_id and c.user_id = 1 
order by p.page_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the your where clause in the on clause and you should get the expected result:

```
select * from pages JOIN control ON page.page_id = control.page_id AND control.user_id = '1'
```

Comment: @Munna Yes as you see

Comment: Sorry Its just showing wrong output :( . it just showing pages table page_id column as second table control_id and page_id :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT p.page_id, p.page_url, p.details, IF(c.user_id=1,c.control_id,NULL), IF(c.user_id=1,c.user_id,NULL) FROM page p LEFT JOIN control c ON(c.page_id=p.page_id)
```